# How do I redefine a search query? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, search, search-terms

I am trying to override the `search query` when loading the search results page. For example: the user enters "Gren Aple", and my script fixes syntax/spelling errors and loads the page with the result of "Green Apple".
I will be glad to any help.

Comment: You Can implement a  Search engine like Solr or elasticSearch that will do this for you in a effective a well

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest installing and enabling **elasticSearch**. It's a great feature, some more information here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to give a try at Elasticsuite : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite